# Angular array.push() creates a duplicate for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the follow HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts">
    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.firstName">
    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.lastName">
    <button ng-click="vm.addNew()">add</button>
</div>
```

and the following code on my Angular controller:

```
vm.contacts = [];

vm.addNew = addNew;

init();

function init() {
    addNew();
}

function addNew() {
    vm.contacts.push({});
}
```

So, when the page is started, the controller adds an empty object to the vm.contacts array.

My problem is: once I fill the fields and click on the add button, instead of creating an array entry with an empty object, angular is duplicating the previuous array entry.

So, if I enter "John" for first name and "Smith" for last name, and then click on the add button, the resulting array will be:

```
[
    {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"},
    {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"}
]
```

And the same contact will be displayed twice.

How do I prevent this from happening?

I've tried both to use `track by $index` on the `ng-repeat` declaration, and `angular.copy()` on the addNew function, and nothing seems to work. I want to be able to add a new empty contact, I do not wish to replicate or duplicate one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've had a similar issue that was resolved by using angular.copy() - [documentation link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Comment: I have tried to use angular.copy() in at least three different ways, but was unable prevent the repetition, @Kyle. :/

Comment: Please add a link to the Plunkr of your current code in the original post

Comment: I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsodvh4a/5/), but it totally works over there, that's why I didn't post it. It fails to work only on my project, which I unfortunately can't share. However, I can't see why it fails here and works there, as the code is basically the same.

Comment: If it's working fine in the jsfiddle then your issue is due to something else in your code. That's why none of the reasonable solutions below are helping you!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">

  {{vm.contacts}}

  <div ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts">
    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.firstName">
    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.lastName">
    <button ng-click="vm.addNew()">add</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)


function MainController($timeout) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.contacts = [{}];

  vm.addNew = addNew;

  function addNew() {
      vm.contacts.push({});
  }    
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/tsodvh4a/)

Comment: @Vinas Does still help you? Because I don't know what the intention is with the `addNew()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work @daan.desmedt, I still get a duplicate. Thjis is a dynamic form.
You can keep adding new contacts. Once you click on the add button, it should create a new array Item and its input fields should be displayed.

Comment: Uh... Can you create a JSFiddle for me please - so i can see the problem?

Comment: It works on fiddle. Don't know why it's not working on the project =P. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tsodvh4a/4/).

Comment: Jea must be some code adding it double? Hard to see from a distance ... Unless if you post your project somewhere online where we can check.

Comment: I had checked that and confirmed this is the only place in the project where something is pushed into `vm.contacts`. Unfortunately, it's a private project and I cannot share it. =(

Comment: Is the `button` wrapped in a `form` element having a `ng-submit`?

Comment: The `button` is indeed inside a `form` element, but there is no `ng-submit` whatsoever in the page. The form submition is handled through a `ng-click` event at another element, outside the `ng-repeat` scope.

Comment: Did you try leaving out the `form` element as test? Besides that, without checking your code - I fear it's diffucult to help you out :(

Comment: Put it outside the `form` and the behaviour was the same. Sitll no luck (or skill haha).

Comment: The issue is clearly not with the code provided in the original post. Please provide the surrounding code if you'd like us to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises here:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.firstName">
    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.lastName">
```

Once the array receives the first and last contact names, the input after that can only be the first and last name stored in contact as the first values are being stored in contact and from there on can only use those values.

Comment: Shouldn't it interpretate that `contact` in this context means `vm.contacts[$index]`?? However, I've tried declaring `ng-model="vm.contacts[$index].firstName"` and it didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure $index is being updated? I think what is happening is somewhere the array is taking the first value entered as the input. For example, when you declare vm.addNew = addNew; then whatever new value added is going to be the first new value added. That's what it looks like to me but I can't follow your code to a great extent.

Comment: Yes @liamguy165. I can print the $index fine while looping. It works on fiddle, it's jsut not working on my project. Kind of a mystery to me :/

Comment: I think there's a clue to what's happening in this what you answered @liamguy165. A closer look revealed that the empty object is created and pushed into the array alright. Only after that, probably when the template is rendered with the new info or something, Angular is getting confused and overwriting the newly created `input` elements with the previous's row data.